# HHVM With FCGI and APACHE show 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: apache, fastcgi, hhvm, mod-fastcgi

Hy,

I have succesfully installed hhvm on my ubuntu 14.04 server. I can run codes from terminal with the following code.

```
hhvm test.php
```

The problem is when I want to access my webpage from browser I get 500 Internal Server Error. In the error log I have found the following lines.

```
[Fri Apr 24 14:26:37.377998 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 40696] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client 192.168.65.221:50382] mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server
[Fri Apr 24 14:26:37.378029 2015] [core:error] [pid 40696] [client 192.168.65.221:50382] End of script output before headers: index.php
```

I am using Apache web server with ISPConfig 3 to handle domains and other stuff.

Does anyone know how to handle this situation?

Thanks in advance, David.

Comment: Is HHVM running, and is it still running after the request? This is often some sort of misconfiguration, OOM problem, or crash.

Comment: Yes, it is still running. Now after some forum topics and reading, I have achieved to get 404 error when opening a page.